# Error on implementing an Interface using interface typecasting

Tags: c#, object, oop, interface

I have a few interfaces that are

```
public interface ISaleOrderManager
{
    Task<IOrderDto> CreateAsync(ICreateOrderDto request);
}

public interface ICreateOrderDto
{
    long? ContactId { get; set; }
    DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    double TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrderDto:ICreateOrderDto,IEntityDto
{ }

public interface IEntityDto
{
    long Id {get;set;}
    bool isDeleted {get; set;}
}
```

also, I have some DTOs as well that are

```
public class CreateSaleOrderDto: ICreateOrderDto
{
   public long? ContactId { get; set; }
   public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
   public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

public class SaleOrderDto : IOrderDto
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public bool isDeleted {get; set;}
    public long? ContactId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And I implement ISaleOrderManager on a class that is

```
public class SaleOrderManager: ISaleOrderManager    
{
    public SaleOrderManager(IRepository<SaleOrder, long> entityRepository)
    {
    }

    public async Task<SaleOrderDto> CreateAsync(CreateSaleOrderDto request)
    {
        var entity = ObjectMapper<SaleOrder>(request);

        entity.Id = await _entityRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(entity);

        return ObjectMapper.Map<SaleOrderDto>(entity);


    }
}
```

So as my code depicts that I have implemented ICreateOrderDto through CreateSaleOrderDto and IOrderDto through SaleOrderDto but I'm still getting an error of "Interface Member is not implemented."

Why do I receive this error and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Please tag the question correctly. The code presented isn't java.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't implement the `Task<IOrderDto> CreateAsync(ICreateOrderDto request)` method in the `SaleOrderManager` class. You made the `CreateAsync` method return a `Task<SaleOrderDto>` instead of a `Task<IOrderDto>`. Also you used a parameter of type `CreateSaleOrderDto` instead of `ICreateOrderDto`.

Comment: I know I haven't implemented it but the thing is ICreateOrderDto is equivalent to CreateSaleOrderDto and the same for IOrderDto.

Comment: @SamiUllah it is not equivalent. You can create 100 classes which all implement `ICreateOrderDto` and all those classes would be different from each-other. Every apple is a fruit, but not all fruits are apples. Your interface is a blueprint for classes, while your classes are the implementations of the interface. If the interface is - rightfully - specified as the type of the parameter, then at the implementation time you need to respect that.

Comment: I upvote this answer, as it is correct,.

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of the method

```
Task<IOrderDto> CreateAsync(ICreateOrderDto request);
```

and this is the attempt for the implementation

```
    public async Task<SaleOrderDto> CreateAsync(CreateSaleOrderDto request)
    {
        var entity = ObjectMapper<SaleOrder>(request);

        entity.Id = await _entityRepository.InsertAndGetIdAsync(entity);

        return ObjectMapper.Map<SaleOrderDto>(entity);


    }
```

I perfectly know that `SaleOrderDto` implements `IOrderDto` and that `CreateSaleOrderDto` implements `ICreateOrderDto`, but this does not qualify as an implementation of the method in the `interface`.

In order to understand the problem, let's consider the possibility that some other class, that may be different from `CreateSaleOrderDto` may also implement `ICreateOrderDto`. If I declare a variable to be an `ISaleOrderManager` and I instantiate this other class, let's call it `MyCustomCreateSaleOrderDto` and pass it to `CreateAsync`, then I justifiably expect your method to work, but it will not work, because your method mistakenly assumed the following:

1. It assumed that each and every `iCreateOrderDto` is a `CreateSaleOrderDto`
2. It assumed that each and every `IOrderDto` is a `SaleOrderDto`

You should aim to write your code in an as abstract manner as possible, so, you should aim to implement your method in a way that it expects a parameter specified as an interface and its return type should also be corresponding to the one specified by the interface, even though they are actual objects at runtime.

Comment: Ok As you say let's assume we have a function definition that is 

**Task<IOrderDto> CreateAsync(ICreateOrderDto request)**

and this method will work perfectly fine if we called this as

**var result= CreateAsync(new CreateSaleOrderDto());**

So every single class that implements these interfaces can be used with this thing.  So this thing should also not be working according to your answer

Comment: @SamiUllah I'm not sure what you think is contradicting my answer, but let me clarify this with a more intuitive analogy. Let's consider that you declare a method that expects a Fruit parameter and Fruit is an interface. When you implement this interface, you need to declare its parameter to be fruit, even though in reality it will be used with actual fruits, like Apple, Orange, Banana (which are all classes that implement the Fruit interface). So, calling `yourmethod(new Banana())` is expected to work properly, even though `yourmethod` expects a type. Banana **is** a Fruit, so

Comment: @SamiUllah you should be able to pass a Banana to your method that was declared to be accepting Fruit parameters. However, if an interface expects a Fruit for `yourmethod`, then the implementation of `yourmethod` cannot be declared to only support Banana, because Orange or Apple is also a Fruit.

Comment: @SamiUllah So, back to `CreateAsync`, which 1. Was declared to accept an `ICreateOrderDto` parameter, while 2. `CreateSaleOrderDto` implements `ICreateOrderDto`, so, we know that 3. Any `CreateSaleOrderDto` is necessarily also an `ICreateOrderDto`, while an `ICreateOrderDto` is not necessarily a `CreateSaleOrderDto`. This means that 4. When `CreateAsync` is implemented, it **must** be in line with its declaration, so we avoid the case when we declared that we support any Fruit, but then we only supported Banana, 5. But, since every **CreateSaleOrderDto** is also an `ICreateOrderDto`,

Comment: @SamiUllah you can call `CreateAsync` by passing a `CreateSaleOrderDto`. So, when you declare your method in your interface, you intend to make it as general as possible, because the more cases your interface covers, the less interfaces you need to implement and the more powerful your code will be. When you implement your interface method, you need to follow its guidelines without deviating from it. And when you call it, you can be more specific, because the whole goal was to support and cover as many possible scenarios as possible.

Comment: @SamiUllah so, your interface method declares the most abstract parameter possible, which is the interface. Then, its implementation cannot contradict the initial declaration. Finally, when you call it, you can pass to the method anything that implements the interface your parameter was specified to be.

Comment: @SamiUllah to provide another analogy, when you say that you have a method of `cook(IFood thefood)`, then, if you implement it, you cannot declare it as `cook(VanillaTort thefood)`, because this would contradict the initial statement, which said that `cook` will work for any `IFood`, while `VanillaTort` does not necessarily cover all possible instances of `IFood`. So, at the implementation you need to specified that `thefood` is essentially an `IFood`. Even though, when you actually call the `cook` method, you may pass a `VanillaTort` instance to it.